# d3 topojson incorrect datatype in webpack/react

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, webpack, topojson

Hi I'm trying to render a map with D3 in a react/webpack project. I'm using [react-d3-wrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-wrap) so that I can put d3 code straight into the react project. Additionally, I'm pulling in the data via having webpack require it as a static file. While doing this,  I'm getting an error that suggests that the datatypes of the topojson file are incorrect:

[image]

This problem occurs when d3 encounters a [string that should be an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252425/d3-js-d3-min-js1-error-path-attribute-d-expected-number-mnan-nanlnan-na). However, inspecting the data in the console indicates that the data really is an int and not a string.

[image]

Furthermore, I'm using topojson to process the file, and that isn't throwing an error (which is what I would expect if topojson encountered string coordinates.)

You can find the topojson [here](http://stackoverflow-public-bucket.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/topo_uscd.json) (Note, clicking on this link will download the json, if you aren't ok with that, dont click.)

Code:

```
import d3Wrap from 'react-d3-wrap';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import topojson from 'topojson';
var topodata = require('../static/topo_uscd.json');

const GerryD3 = d3Wrap({
    update(svg, data, options) {

        var width = svg.width, height = svg.height;

        var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
            .scale(1200)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

        var path = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        var d3svg = d3.select(svg);

        var g = d3svg.append("g");

        var draw = function (us) {
            g.selectAll("path")
                .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.uscd).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "district")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("fill", "#adadad");
            g.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.uscd, function (a, b) {
                    return a !== b;
                 }))
                 .attr("class", "boundary")
                 .attr("d", path);
        }(data);

        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
    }
});

export default class Gerrymandering extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <GerryD3 data={topodata} width={document.documentElement.clientWidth - 250} height={document.documentElement.clientHeight-150}/>
        )
    }
}
```

What is going wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I made a separate project using the same code except I use `d3.json` to request the topojson file - and it works! This suggests to me that somehow using `require` is messing with the data in some way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came in with the line:

```
var width = svg.width, height = svg.height;
```

It turns out that the `svg` that gets passed in has a `SVGAnimatedLength` for it's width/height object instead of a number. Translating the projection with these objects was what caused the error.